kotlin multiplatform expect/actual usage
I used the KMP Library Wizard to generate a boilerplate project to support both Android and iOS.  I can't figure out why the following code is not flagged by the compiler.  I don't understand how the signature of the AppModule is different and the compiler is not complaining - note the Android "actual signature" vs the "expect signature"
From commonMain:
expect class AppModule {
    val blueFalcon: BlueFalcon
}

From androidMain:
actual class AppModule(private val context: Context) {
    actual val blueFalcon: BlueFalcon
        get() = BlueFalcon(context as ApplicationContext)
}

From nativeMain
actual class AppModule {
    actual val blueFalcon: BlueFalcon
        get() = BlueFalcon(ApplicationContext())
}

I have attempted to duplicate the expect/actual use of this for a different purpose and the compiler complained about the Android "actual" as follows:
Actual class 'BroadcastHandler' has no corresponding members for expected class members: 
public constructor BroadcastHandler() defined in CommonSupport.BroadcastHandler The following declaration is incompatible because number of value parameters is different:
public constructor BroadcastHandler(context: Context) defined in CommonSupport.BroadcastHandler

I am perhaps missing something fundamental.  Please, explain why the compiler is happy with AppModule expect/actual

Sorry but I used the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard: https://kmp.jetbrains.com/

the error is complaining about BroadcastHandler but you're only showing code of AppModule. Do you have such class?

You are correct of course.  I am trying to understand how the signature of  AppModule can be different between the expect and actual.  Note that the message about BroadcastHandler is pointing to the fact that the constructor of the actual has the "context" parameter where the expect constructor does not.  I don't understand why AppModule (the posted code) works.

expect class of AppModule doesn't have a constructor, so it doesn't expect any constructors to be defined in actual, and each constructor you actually define is platform only. with BroadcastHandler you probably have an expect constructor, so this class can be created from common code, and this requires you to define this particular constructor on each platform

Phil - I was missing this fundamental notion.  Thanks for you help!
